# Name of my central heat pump unit

Tags: hvac

This sounds crazy but i cant find out what brand central package unit i have. Ive looked everywhere on the internet.. I believe its a york , because there is a address on the bottom of this tag saìys york drive and thats the only company that kinda fits . no one really nose mayone someone can help me with a site or tell me if your for sure what brand it is Thanks*[![enter

```
image
```

description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV4te.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV4te.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Did you search the model number?

Comment: So it is this question here : https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/161903/97780

Comment: Yes and ive called Grainger Industrial Supply House they are the only one that I can get to sell to the public without ordering it offline and they have no idea who makes this central heat pump unit just really looking to find out what unit I have believe it's a York but what kind what series I really don't know if it's a York that's the best educated guess I can come up with Monday I'm going to pick up the capacitor it's bad I'm going today to see if maybe any AC company little or big will sell me one for a little more money on the side

Comment: It takes special tools and knowledge to swap out the compressor, a recovery system, vacuum pump line set , knowledge on how to silver solder and last knowledge of the type of Freon in the system. Did you know that the EPA can levy fines up to 20k for opening an HVAC system without a license.